# How to access worklight.properties in java file under server/java/mypackage

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

Im using worklight 6.0 and I know how to use worklight.properties file in adapter xml 
But,How to access worklight.properties in java file under server/java/mypackage

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ClassLoader's getResourceAsStream method in order to access the worklight.prperties file. Here is a code example that retrieves the project build number:

```
public String getPublicBuildVersion() {
    try{
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf/worklight.properties"));
        return p.getProperty("project.build.version");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "Exp: " + e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

There is a limitation when ucsing this method. When I tried that it worked, but after I updated the application, this code threw an exception during the getResourceAsStream call. The only way I found to make the code work again is to restart the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String getWorklightProperty(String propertyName){
    return WorklightConfiguration.getInstance().getString("propertyName");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read the property you are interested using `WL.Server.configuration` API and then passing these values to your Java code. [The Infocenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/t_calling_java_code_from_a_javas.html) has information on how this can be achieved